# Connecting to Amazon RDS DB through Sequel Pro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect Sequel Pro to my Amazon RDS Instance, and while it looks like I have set my security groups correctly to allow access to all-traffic, attempting to connect to it still fails.

This is what I did:

- In IAM, I created a new user, and added that user to a group that has a policy that allows full access to RDS.
- For the security group that is attached to my RDS instance, I added an Inbound rule to allow all traffic of type MYSQL/Aurora

However, when I enter the endpoint displayed in the RDS screen, along with the username and password I created through IAM, I get an access denied message. Any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: IAM is not used for access to the DB. IAM is used for management of AWS resources (for example resizing the RDS DB and terminating it). When you created the DB, you supplied admin credentials for the DB. Use those in your SQL client. And in your DB security group, you need to allow inbound access from your IP to the DB (presumably on port 3306).

Comment: Thanks for that info @jarmod; so based on that info, how can I give other users access to the db, without having everyone use the same credentials?

Comment: When you created the DB, you supplied a set of admin credentials. Do not share those with others. What you need to do is create additional user accounts, one per user, and give each the appropriate (non-admin) permissions. This is a totally standard MySQL thing, nothing to do with RDS. For more, see http://dev.n0ise.net/2012/09/amazon-rds-mysql-add-additional-users-with-limited-previledges/ or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html.